# Expo app upgrade gives Ivariant violation : Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: react-native, expo

[image][image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEDdq.png)[image][image][image]I have been running my code in the Expo app without any issues. However after I upgraded the Expo App, I am getting the error

```
**Objects are not valid as a React child**.
```

Now even when I go to earlier commits, which were working for sure, I get the same error. A funny thing, the error does not tell me exactly on which line of code or component the problem is coming from. I have taken screenshots.